# iOS MapView or just nor UIView when dealing with static map image

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, android-mapview

I have an image of a mall layout and want to know if it is better to use the MapView or just plain old ImageView?  All I want to do is display this image and place some markers on it.  There is no need to geocode etc.. What should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't replace the map tiles of `MKMapView` with your own graphics, it isn't really an option in your case. A plain image view is fine as long as your map does not need zooming and isn't very large (in pixel dimensions). If it is, tiling the map image and using `CATiledLayer` (what `MKMapView` uses internally) might be the correct choice.